# Tracking workload over time

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have a work database that lists:

- Type of job
- Date job started
- Date job finished

I have been asked if I can produce a report that can be run each Monday (or whenever) that:

a) shows the current workload and

b) shows what the workload was the previous week (and each previous week of the current financial year - 1/4/18 - 31/3/19).

Its date parameters would be:

```
week 1: 1/4/18 - 7/4/18

week 2: 8/4/18 - 15/4/18 etc
```

so I would be looking at live workload totals as at 1/4/18, 8/4/18 etc

If there is no date in the 'date job finished' field then a job is considered live.

So for example if we look at these 4 jobs:

```
job 1 started 31/3/18 finished 21/4/18
job 2 started 2/4/18 finished 20/4/18
job3 started 6/4/18 unfinished
and job 4 start on 10/4/18 unfinished
```

And ran a report on 22/4/18 I would need its output to be, sowing what the workload was on these weeks:

```
Workload:

Week 1(1/4/18)    3
Week 2 (8/4/18)   3
Week 3            4
Week 4            2
```

3 3 4 2

So in terms of current workload - that's easy and just a count of jobs where the 'date job finished' field is null.

However I'm struggling to work out how to calculate the workload over time - basically I need a query to work out how to get an accurate count of when the date job finished field was null in a particular week.

Any help / assistance would be massively appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think Group By Week should do you

Comment: Thanks for getting back. My problem is how to get the financial weeks to appear (e.g. week 1 to be the first week of the current financial year) and in addition produce the t-sql to show if a particular job was current in a particular week. That's where I'm struggling.

Comment: Then you need to create a calendar table, [here's one example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), and join to that

Comment: I don't have the permissions to add a calendar table. Ideally I'd like to create something just using the start and finish dates in the data table I'm using ( as mentioned above).
So instead of say week 1, week 2 above could I not run a query to show: Today's current workload; Last week's workload? so for example as of now we have 1 live job,  this time last week we had two: the second job was open between 1/7/18 - 5/7/18 so is closed now. I'm simply trying to capture the number of jobs open at a particular date e.g.They had a start date and their finished date was > that particular date.

Comment: You need to challenge the decision of not being to create a calendar table. Anyway...

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution based on my understanding of your problem

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( JobType NVARCHAR(50), JobStart DATETIME, JobFinish DATETIME )
INSERT INTO @t
(JobType,JobStart, JobFinish)
VALUES
('Type1', '20180604', '20180611')
,('Type2', '20180611', '20180626')
,('Type3', '20180618', '20180620')
,('Type4', '20180625', NULL)

/*
Week Date Ranges
1.  04062018    to  10062018
2.  11062018    to  17062018
3.  18062018    to  24062018
4.  25062018    to  01072018
*/
```

--To calculate finished jobs that were Started in Week 1 04062018 to 10062018 and finished after this week

```
SELECT
     T.JobType
    ,T.JobStart
    ,T.JobFinish 
FROM @t T
WHERE (T.JobStart >= '20180604' AND T.JobStart <= '20180610') AND T.JobFinish > '20180610'
```

output

```
JobType JobStart    JobFinish
Type1   2018-06-04 00:00:00.000 2018-06-11 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the dataset.